# How Levenshtein's edit distance algorithm works?

Tags: algorithm, levenshtein-distance

I was going through [Levenshtein distance algorithm](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Levenshtein_distance) in which I grasped some of its initial steps but in subsequent steps when it starts counting "cost" ,I had hard time to understand it. I don't get the purpose of counting cost and how it is helping the algorithm to achieve its goal. Please help me understand this algorithm.

Comment: Take a look at this: http://cs.stackexchange.com/questions/28734/edit-distance-levenshtein-distance-algorithm-explanation

Comment: Also here is a good explanation along with a demo where you could change weights (i.e. costs) for every operation and check the results: http://odur.let.rug.nl/kleiweg/lev/

Answer (score 2):

There are many different ways to edit the first string by means of insertions/deletions/substitutions to get the second string (actually infinitely many). Each has a specific count of elementary edit operation.

The Levenshtein distance is defined as the minimum number of operations required, i.e. the length of the shortest sequence. This number is well defined, even though it can be achieved by several different edit sequences.

This is very similar to the case of the Euclidean distance: you can go from one point to another following various trajectories, but only the straight line achieves the minimum path length.

UPDATE:

Need to add that assigning different costs to the different operations provides more flexibility and allows to give favor to one or another. Even more, you can assign individual weights to every characters, so that, for instance, trading a 'O' for a '0' is considered more "serious" than inserting a space.

And the cost minimization principle remains.

Answer (score 0):

The [Levenshtein distance](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Levenshtein_distance) for two strings `a` and `b` can be calculated using [Dynamic Programming](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Dynamic_programming), which here defines a table which stores the cost for pairs of prefixes of `a` and `b`. Here the cost is exactly the Levenshtein distance, i.e. the number of edit steps.